# Error Running Vba Code

Tags: vba

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
    (ByRef pCaller As LongPtr, _
     ByVal szURL As String, _
     ByVal szFileName As String, _
     ByVal dwReserve As Long, _
     ByRef lpfnCB As LongPtr) _
As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
    (ByRef pCaller As Long, _
     ByVal szURL As String, _
     ByVal szFileName As String, _
     ByVal dwReserve As Long, _
     ByRef lpfnCB As Long) _
As Long
#End If

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp"

Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strPath As String

'~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

If Ret = 0 Then
ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
Else
ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
End If
Next i
EndSub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cmQa.png)
Error is given below:

Comment: Have you tryied to declare string variable e.g. `dim url = ws.Range("B" & i).Value` and then use this variable in the call `Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, strPath, 0, 0)`? Bacause `Range.Value` is not of type string and the function requires string parameter.

Comment: Well, I know nothing about VBA. Can you please make the necessary changes and repost this whole code so that it starts working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting the parameter in the API function, this is what I used.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
    "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long


Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"

Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strPath As String

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
    strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"
    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)
    If Ret = 0 Then
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
    Else
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

To have the file path if the download was successfull, try it.
So if the file is downloaded successfully the path will be placed in column C and the msg "File successfully downloaded" in column D otherwise column C will contain "Unable to download the file".

```
For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
    strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"
    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)
    If Ret = 0 Then
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = strPath
        ws.Range("D" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
    Else
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: It still says : "Type Mismatch".

Comment: Just noticed that you have declared a variable called Ret as long and using Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0) which is wrong, just call the function itself and remove the Ret = and it should work after changing the datatype as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Try using If URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0) = 0 then, and see if that works for you.

Comment: I have followed your suggestions but  now the error is  "Compile Error: Function call on left hand side of assignment must return variant or object" and "URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0) =" is highlighted blue.

Comment: Get rid of parenthesis when calling the function alone i.e. function name and then arguments without parenthesis.

Comment: BTW see what dee has suggested in his answer.

Comment: I have used it without quotes and it gives the error.

Comment: Well it should work. Are you sure that you can access the file without any login credentials and also try to change the destination path.

Comment: I have also changed the destination path but the error is the same. Can you please check it yourself ? The sample data is given below in case :  Column A:                                                                                                1
Column B:                                           http://hardwareinsights.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/registration.png

Comment: You have misspelled one parameter in API function and it should be ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr and ByVal dwReserved As Long for two versions and when I ran the code at my end then, the code ran without an issue but got "Unable to download the file" in column C.

Comment: Now the error is "You must terminate #if block with an #Endif"

Comment: That means you have still some of your previous code on the top. Replace all your code with the suggested code.

Comment: Yes Now this is working fine now. Thank you very much for the great help. Can we make a one more column in excel that specifies the directory for each downloaded image and the VBA code is saving the file in the respective directory as per the excel file ? In other words can we make some change in the code to achieve the aforementioned objective?

Comment: Edited the solution and added the tweaked For Loop.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I mean if the excel has column D where we already have a file path so that the image file is saved in that directory. We  define the path ourselves. Then the code download the images and saves the files accordingly in the mentioned directories in column D.

Comment: In that case if the path in column D in each cell is not ended with a back slash "\" then replace the strPath line inside the For loop with strPath = ws.Range("D" & i).Value & "\" & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg" and if the path ends with a back slash then use strPath = ws.Range("D" & i).Value & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

Comment: Also if that answers your question, please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Comment: But the code has already line "Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp\" " which specifies the file path. What should I do with this ?

Comment: You don't need that constant variable if the file path is mentioned in column D.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. For more info have a look e.g. [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/downloadfile.aspx).

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
    "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp"

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim urlFileName As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        strPath = FolderName & "\" & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"
        urlFileName = ws.Range("B" & i).Value
        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, urlFileName, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

> Data on Sheet

```
HeaderA    |   HeaderB
SomeImage1 |   http://www.someaddress.com/Imgs/SomeImage1.jpg
```